# VBA unexpected reach of string size limit

Tags: excel, vba

I am facing an "out of string space" error while trying to assign large strings in vba:

```
Dim MyData As String
MyData = Space$(321262258)
```

The number of characters is clearly under 2^31 expected limit. What could be the reason of such an error ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: I'm actually limited to `Space$(255918061)` which is less than 2^28 characters...

Comment: I first thought it was because of the integer type of Space input argument (see MSDN), but it seems to accept Long type as well.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a somewhat opaque error -- opaque in the sense that it would require detailed understanding of the internals of the VBA interpreter to answer. MSDN says about this error:

> Visual Basic permits you to use very large strings. However, the requirements of other programs and the way you manipulate your strings may cause this error.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa264524(v=vs.60).aspx

I can't find anything in the documentation which suggests a limit of around 2^27 for many built-in functions such as Space() or String(), as well as concatenation operators like + or &, but these limits seem to exist. There seems to be a poorly documented discrepancy between the maximum possible size of a string in memory (say read in from a text file) and the maximum possible  size of string which can be built up from built-in VBA functions and operators. Odd. I would be interested if anyone knows of a kludge which can in pure VBA construct the string which Space$(321262258) or even Space(2^31 -1 ) is trying to construct.

Comment: Thanks for your support. Ok...I feared that I was reaching some uncontrollable vb limitations. The purpose of assigning such a large string is to read a large file (321MB) in one go (using "open _path_ for _binary_ as #FNb") and splitting it by line. 
Is there other working around than buffering the access which increases a lot the computation time ?