# Can we add more than 255 characters inside Word document property

Tags: ms-word, ms-office, limit

I have a word document .docx which contain a property, currently when i tried to add more than 255 charterers inside the word document property i will get an error that the it is invalid. so can i exerted this limit? Thanks

[image]

Comment: I think the error explains that you can’t. What you can do is combine multiple doc properties to contain the account number (assuming that is the value that exceeds 255 characters)

Comment: @Boeryepes so we can not exceeds this limit?

Comment: If this property is defined in SharePoint, SharePoint sets a maximum of 255 characters for a column of type "single line of text". In that case, it may be possible change the column type, but even then you may find that there is a maximum length.

Comment: @jonsson no i am using the Multiple line of text field in SharePoint which can hold more than 255 chars.. the issue is with the word property itself

Comment: You can use Content Controls which are **mapped to XML** to hold more. The simplest example of these are the Document Property Content Controls. SharePoint allows you to add to these. https://addbalance.com/word/MappedControls.htm#PageStart and https://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/EnhancedDocProp_AddIn.html.

Comment: @Charles Kenyon - Quite. It seems they are already mapped. The question is whether SP is imposing its own constraint. ISTR something about this but haven't had a SharePoint account for a while so can't check.

Answer (score 1):

This is the max size of the document property. You can't change it. Instead you may consider using document variables and DOCVARIABLE fields, which do not have such a limit.

Also consider writing long data into multiple properties like described in the [How to overcome custom document property size limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42120915/how-to-overcome-custom-document-property-size-limit) post.

Comment: ok thanks .. so if i use document variables will i be ale to populate them using Power automate flows? Thanks

Comment: I don't think these are old-style Custom Document Properties, which do have a 255 limit. I think they are SharePoint columns mapped via a CustomXmlPart to a plain text Content Control. Multiline plain text Content controls allow far more than 255 characters, as does the Custom XML Part where the data is stored.

But ISTR there *is* a constraint because of course when Sharepoint serves a document, it populates the relevant Custom XML Part, but ISTR it imposes an arbitrary, undocumented constraint. Just can't find my very old notes on the subject.

Comment: @jonsson sorry i did not get your point. you mean if i use document variables instead of document properties i will not be able to populate them using Power automate?

Comment: @john john My comment was really in response to Eugene's Answer.

I don't know whether you can populate Document Variables using Power Automate or not. Probably not, because Document Variables are "very old technology" from a Microsoft perspective.

Comment: I thought that SP allowed more than 255 in some cases but after finding my old experiments it seems it will truncate to 255. [SP populates the .docx with the data and an XML Schema describing the data, e.g. <xsd:restriction base="dms:Text">
<xsd:maxLength value="255"/>]