How to store and retrieve binary files within an excel workbook using VBA?
Is it possible to store a binary file within an excel workbook for later retrieval? For example sound files that any user can play back later.

I use this procedure to store and retrieve binary files within a workbook. It might be useful for you. The binary files are stored in CustomDocumentProperties under the workbook object. As this property is not compatible with the character &H0000 the data is encoded first with a simple algorithm. Usage as follows.

Run StoreFile(filepath) to store any binary file within the workbook. The file will be permanently retained in the document when saved and reopened by any user.
Run GetFile(filename) to retrive the file. This function returns the path to the "recreated file" in the windows temp folder.
Run ClearAll to remove all files from the workbook and clear out created files in the windows temp folder.

Option Explicit

Sub StoreFile(ByVal sPath As String)
'Stores the filename given by sPath internally as a CustomDocumentProperty
    Dim fNo As Long, b() As Byte, s As String, sFileName As String
    
'Read the binary file
    fNo = FreeFile
    Open sPath For Binary Access Read As fNo
    ReDim b(LOF(fNo) - 1)
    Get fNo, , b
    Close fNo
    
'Compresses and clears the file from &H0000 (which isn't compatible with CustomDocumentProperties
    s = NonZCompress(b)
    sFileName = Mid(sPath, InStrRev(sPath, "\") + 1) 'Stores the file without "path" information

'Removes any old version of the file
    On Error Resume Next
        ThisWorkbook.CustomDocumentProperties("#BIN:" & sFileName).Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
    
'Adds the propery
    ThisWorkbook.CustomDocumentProperties.Add Name:="#BIN:" & sFileName, LinkToContent:=False, Type:=msoPropertyTypeString, Value:=s
End Sub

Function GetFile(ByVal sFileName As String) As String
'Recreates the file as stored in CustomDocumentProperty in the windows temp folder
'Function returns the path to the recreated file.
'Returns empty string if no file with given filename exists
    Dim CP As DocumentProperty, fNo As Long, b() As Byte, s As String
    
'Clears any path information from user input
    sFileName = Mid(sFileName, InStrRev(sFileName, "\") + 1)
    
'Checks if CustomDocumentProperty exists
    On Error Resume Next
        Set CP = ThisWorkbook.CustomDocumentProperties("#BIN:" & sFileName)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If CP Is Nothing Then Exit Function
    
'Decompresses the file and stores it in byte array b
    b = CP.Value
    b = NonZDecompress(b)
    
'Saves the byte array to the windows temp folder
    GetFile = Environ("temp") & "\" & sFileName
    fNo = FreeFile
    Open GetFile For Binary Access Write As fNo
    Put fNo, , b
    Close fNo
End Function

Sub ClearAll()
'Clears out all created custom properties and removes any temp files
    On Error Resume Next
    While ThisWorkbook.CustomDocumentProperties.Count > 0
        With ThisWorkbook.CustomDocumentProperties(1)
            If Left(.Name, 5) = "#BIN:" Then
                Kill Environ("temp") & "\" & Mid(.Name, 6)
                .Delete
            End If
        End With
    Wend
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub

For compression/decompression into a byte array without &H0000 I use these functions:
Option Explicit

Function NonZCompress(b() As Byte) As Byte()
    Dim out() As Byte, i_source As Long, i_dest As Long, ZeroSeq As Long, len_b As Long
'Compresses any byte array into a new byte array without &H0000 in it
'First 4 bytes is the length of the input
'Replaces &H0001 with &H0001FFFF
'Replaces any mutiple (N) of &H0000 with &H0001XXXX where XXXX is the number of repeats.
'N ranges from 0 to 65534 (&H0000 to &HFFFE)
    
    ReDim out(UBound(b))
    len_b = UBound(b) + 1
    out(0) = len_b \ 16777216
    out(1) = (len_b Mod 16777216) \ 65536
    out(2) = (len_b Mod 65536) \ 256
    out(3) = len_b Mod 256
    i_dest = 4
    For i_source = 0 To len_b - 1 Step 2
        If b(i_source) = 0 Then
            If b(i_source + 1) = 0 Then '&H0000 found
                If ZeroSeq = 65534 Then
                    'out(i_dest) = 0
                    out(i_dest + 1) = 1
                    out(i_dest + 2) = 255
                    out(i_dest + 3) = 254
                    i_dest = i_dest + 4
                    ZeroSeq = 1
                Else
                    ZeroSeq = ZeroSeq + 1
                End If
            Else  '&H00XX found (XX<>00)
                If ZeroSeq <> 0 Then
                    'out(i_dest) = 0
                    out(i_dest + 1) = 1
                    out(i_dest + 2) = ZeroSeq \ 256
                    out(i_dest + 3) = ZeroSeq Mod 256
                    i_dest = i_dest + 4
                    ZeroSeq = 0
                End If
                If b(i_source + 1) = 1 Then  '&H0001 found
                    'out(i_dest) = 0
                    out(i_dest + 1) = 1
                    out(i_dest + 2) = 255
                    out(i_dest + 3) = 255
                    i_dest = i_dest + 4
                Else  '&H00XX found (XX<>00 and XX<>01)
                    'out(i_dest) = 0
                    out(i_dest + 1) = b(i_source + 1)
                    i_dest = i_dest + 2
                End If
            End If
        Else '&HXXYY found (XX<>00) "normal Word"
            If ZeroSeq <> 0 Then
                'out(i_dest) = 0
                out(i_dest + 1) = 1
                out(i_dest + 2) = ZeroSeq \ 256
                out(i_dest + 3) = ZeroSeq Mod 256
                i_dest = i_dest + 4
                ZeroSeq = 0
            End If
            out(i_dest) = b(i_source)
            out(i_dest + 1) = b(i_source + 1)
            i_dest = i_dest + 2
        End If
        If i_dest + 7 > UBound(out) Then 'Make sure we do not run out of space for next cycle
            ReDim Preserve out(UBound(out) + 100000)
        End If
    Next
    If ZeroSeq <> 0 Then
        'out(i_dest) = 0
        out(i_dest + 1) = 1
        out(i_dest + 2) = ZeroSeq \ 256
        out(i_dest + 3) = ZeroSeq Mod 256
        i_dest = i_dest + 4
        ZeroSeq = 0
    End If

'Special case where byte count is odd. Pad with &HFF
    If (len_b Mod 2) = 1 Then
        out(i_dest) = b(UBound(b))
        out(i_dest + 1) = 255
        i_dest = i_dest + 2
    End If
    
    ReDim Preserve out(i_dest - 1)
    NonZCompress = out
End Function

Function NonZDecompress(b() As Byte) As Byte()
'Decompresses any byte array compressed with NonZCompress
    Dim out() As Byte, i_source As Long, i_dest As Long, ZeroSeq As Boolean, len_b As Long
    
'Set the output size
    ReDim out(b(0) * 16777216 + b(1) * 65536 + b(2) * 256& + b(3) - 1)
    i_dest = 0
    
'Start decompress
    For i_source = 4 To UBound(b) Step 2
        If b(i_source) = 0 And b(i_source + 1) = 1 Then 'Special case &H0001
            i_source = i_source + 2
            If b(i_source) = 255 And b(i_source + 1) = 255 Then 'Signifies the &H0001 should be added
                'out(i_dest) = 0
                out(i_dest + 1) = 1
                i_dest = i_dest + 2
            Else 'Signifies that multiple &H0000 should be added
                i_dest = i_dest + 512& * b(i_source) + 2& * b(i_source + 1)
            End If
        Else 'Normal case
            out(i_dest) = b(i_source)
            If i_dest < UBound(out) Then out(i_dest + 1) = b(i_source + 1) 'The condition is used to handle last odd byte if any
            i_dest = i_dest + 2
        End If
    Next
    NonZDecompress = out
End Function

Example usage. Store some windows media files in the excel file to play sounds based on user input. First run StoreInternally to store the file. You only nee to run this once in a workbook. Then use the Sound sub to play different sounds.

Note: Storage is rather efficient as it is stored as a unicode string with little overhead. Adding the 4 media files (972 kB) gives an xlsm with a total filesize of only 725 kB.
Option Explicit

Public Declare Function sndPlaySound32 Lib "winmm.dll" Alias "sndPlaySoundA" (ByVal lpszSoundName As String, ByVal uFlags As Long) As Long

Public Enum SOUND_TYPE
    OK = 1
    MISPLACED = 2
    COMPLETE = 3
    NEW_LOCATION = 4
End Enum

Sub Sound(ST As SOUND_TYPE)
    Select Case ST
        Case OK:           sndPlaySound32 GetFile("Windows Ding.wav"), &H1
        Case MISPLACED:    sndPlaySound32 GetFile("Windows Hardware Fail.wav"), &H1
        Case COMPLETE:     sndPlaySound32 GetFile("tada.wav"), &H1
        Case NEW_LOCATION: sndPlaySound32 GetFile("Windows Logon.wav"), &H1
    End Select
End Sub

Sub StoreInternally()
    Const MediaFolder = "C:\Windows\Media\"
    StoreFile MediaFolder & "Windows Ding.wav"
    StoreFile MediaFolder & "Windows Hardware Fail.wav"
    StoreFile MediaFolder & "tada.wav"
    StoreFile MediaFolder & "Windows Logon.wav"
End Sub

Hope you find this useful!


Great answer.  Base64 encoding would also work here?   Also "Custom XML Parts" are an alternative to custom properties: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42120915/how-to-overcome-custom-document-property-size-limit

A Base64 approach with two alternatives for storage location:

content stored on a worksheet
or
content stored in a CustomXmlPart (MS docs on this area bit iffy but managed to fumble my way through...)

Option Explicit

Sub Tester()
    'Store a couple of files to a worksheet and then
    '   re-create them from the stored versions
    StoreFileToWorksheet files, "C:\Temp\stories.pdf"
    CreateFileFromWorksheet files, "stories.pdf", "C:\Temp\stories2.pdf"

    StoreFileToWorksheet files, "C:\Temp\rows.pptm"
    CreateFileFromWorksheet files, "rows.pptm", "C:\Temp\rows2.pptm"
    
    'Same thing using CustomXmlParts
    ListXmlStoredFiles ThisWorkbook
    
    StoreFileToCustomXmlPart ThisWorkbook, "C:\Temp\stories.pdf"
    CreateFileFromCustomXmlPart ThisWorkbook, "stories.pdf", "C:\Temp\stories33.pdf"
    
    StoreFileToCustomXmlPart ThisWorkbook, "C:\Temp\rows.pptm"
    CreateFileFromCustomXmlPart ThisWorkbook, "rows.pptm", "C:\Temp\rows33.pptm"
    
End Sub

'----------- storing and retreiving using CustomXmlParts -------------------

'Convert file at `filePath` to Base64 and store in CustomXmlParts
Sub StoreFileToCustomXmlPart(wb As Workbook, filePath As String)
    
    Dim b64 As String, ans, id As String
    Dim fName As String, files As CustomXMLPart, file As CustomXMLNode
    
    fName = fileName(filePath)
    id = "FILE_" & fName
    
    Set files = XmlFileContainer(wb)
    If files Is Nothing Then
        Set files = XmlFileContainer(wb, True) 'create
    Else
        Set file = files.SelectSingleNode("//*[@fileId = '" & id & "']")
        If Not file Is Nothing Then
            ans = MsgBox("Stored file '" & fName & "' already exists.  Replace?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion)
            If ans <> vbYes Then Exit Sub
            file.Delete
        End If
    End If
    
    b64 = EncodeBase64(GetBytes(filePath))            'get file content as Base64 string
    
    'add a node for the file and set the id attribute
    files.DocumentElement.AppendChildNode Name:="file", NodeValue:=b64
    Set file = files.DocumentElement.ChildNodes(files.DocumentElement.ChildNodes.count)
    file.AppendChildNode Name:="fileId", NodeType:=msoCustomXMLNodeAttribute, NodeValue:=id

End Sub

'Find file content (Base64) in CusomXmlParts and save to disk
Sub CreateFileFromCustomXmlPart(wb As Workbook, fileName As String, saveAs As String)
    
    Dim b64 As String, id As String
    Dim files As CustomXMLPart, file As CustomXMLNode, ff
    
    Set files = XmlFileContainer(wb)
    If files Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "No stored files in this workbook", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    id = "FILE_" & fileName
    Set file = files.SelectSingleNode("//*[@fileId = '" & id & "']")
    If Not file Is Nothing Then
        On Error Resume Next
        Kill saveAs   'remove any existing file at "save" path
        On Error GoTo 0
        b64 = file.Text
        ff = FreeFile
        Open saveAs For Binary As ff  'write out binary content
        Put ff, 1, DecodeBase64(b64)
        Close ff
    Else
        MsgBox "File '" & fileName & "' not found!", vbExclamation
    End If
End Sub

'Get the custom XML part used for storing files in workbook `wb`
'  Optionally, create the custom part if not found
Function XmlFileContainer(wb As Workbook, _
                          Optional bCreateIfMissing As Boolean = False) As CustomXMLPart
    Const CustXmlPartsNS As String = "stored:b64:files"
    On Error Resume Next
    Set XmlFileContainer = wb.CustomXMLParts.SelectByNamespace(CustXmlPartsNS)(1)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If XmlFileContainer Is Nothing And bCreateIfMissing Then
        Set XmlFileContainer = wb.CustomXMLParts.Add( _
          "<?xml version='1.0' ?><StoredFiles xmlns='" & CustXmlPartsNS & "'></StoredFiles>")
    End If
End Function

Sub ListXmlStoredFiles(wb As Workbook)
    Dim files As CustomXMLPart, nd As CustomXMLNode
    Set files = XmlFileContainer(wb)
    If files Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Debug.Print "Stored files:"
    For Each nd In files.DocumentElement.ChildNodes
        Debug.Print , Replace(nd.Attributes(1).NodeValue, "FILE_", "")
    Next nd
End Sub
'----------- /storing and retreiving using CustomXmlParts -------------------

'----------- storing and retreiving using worksheet -------------------

'Convert file at `filePath` to Base64 and store on worksheet `ws`
Sub StoreFileToWorksheet(ws As Worksheet, filePath As String)
    
    Const CHUNK As Long = 30000 'Excel cell content limit is ~32k
    Dim b64 As String, i As Long, ans, s As String
    Dim nLines As Long, rStart, rEnd, fName As String
    
    fName = fileName(filePath)
    rStart = Application.Match(fName, ws.Columns(1), 0)
    If Not IsError(rStart) Then 'file name already stored?
        ans = MsgBox("File '" & fName & "' already exists.  Replace?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion)
        If ans <> vbYes Then Exit Sub
        rEnd = Application.Match("/" & fName, ws.Columns(1), 0)
        ws.Rows(rStart).Resize(1 + (rEnd - rStart)).Delete 'remove existing version
    End If
    
    rStart = ws.Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(2).Row 'start position
    
    b64 = EncodeBase64(GetBytes(filePath))            'get file content as Base64 string
    nLines = Application.Ceiling(Len(b64) / CHUNK, 1) 'chunking to fit within cell limit
    For i = 1 To nLines                               'populate b64 content
        s = Mid(b64, 1 + ((i - 1) * CHUNK), CHUNK)
        'Add a leading ' to make sure XL doesn't try to process value
        '     as a formula (leading to wierd "out of memory" errors)
        ws.Cells(rStart + (i - 1), "B").Value2 = "'" & s
    Next i
    ws.[B:B].WrapText = False  'Excel keeps resetting this when adding long content...
    files.Cells(rStart, "A") = fName                         'flag start of content
    ws.Cells(rStart, "A").Offset(nLines).Value = "/" & fName 'flag end of content
    
End Sub
    
   
'Read file content (as Base64 string labelled with `fileName`) from cells,
'  convert back to binary and save to path `saveAs`.
Sub CreateFileFromWorksheet(ws As Worksheet, fileName As String, saveAs As String)
    Dim rStart, rEnd, b64, arr, i As Long, v As String, ff
    
    rStart = Application.Match(fileName, ws.Columns(1), 0)
    If IsError(rStart) Then   'file content exists with this label?
        MsgBox "File '" & fileName & "' not found on sheet '" & ws.Name & "'", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    rEnd = Application.Match("/" & fileName, ws.Columns(1), 0) 'find the end of the content
    arr = ws.Cells(rStart, "B").Resize(1 + (rEnd - rStart)).Value 'read as array
    For i = 1 To UBound(arr, 1) 'rebuild final string
        v = arr(i, 1)
        If Len(v) > 0 Then b64 = b64 & v
    Next i
    
    On Error Resume Next
    Kill saveAs   'remove any existing file at "save" path
    On Error GoTo 0

    ff = FreeFile
    Open saveAs For Binary As ff  'write out binary content
    Put ff, 1, DecodeBase64(b64)
    Close ff
End Sub

'----------- /storing and retreiving using worksheet -------------------

'----------- helper methods

Function DecodeBase64(ByVal strData As String) As Byte()
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument").createElement("b64")
        .DataType = "bin.base64"
        .Text = strData
        DecodeBase64 = .nodeTypedValue
    End With
End Function

Function EncodeBase64(bytes) As String
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument").createElement("b64")
        .DataType = "bin.base64"
        .nodeTypedValue = bytes
        EncodeBase64 = .Text
    End With
End Function

'Get file binary content
Function GetBytes(filePath As String)
    With CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
        .Open
        .Type = 1 'ADODB.adTypeBinary
        .LoadFromFile filePath
        GetBytes = .Read
        .Close
    End With
End Function

'Get file name from full path
Function fileName(filePath As String)
    fileName = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject").GetFileName(filePath)
End Function



You can utilize the standard "Insert Object" feature of Excel:

For the object of a registered type, the standard action is available: Shapes("ObjectName").OLEFormat.Verb Verb:=xlPrimary.

True. But can you access the binary content in a sample way. I guess it depends on why you add the file from the start. My version is very generic and will work for any data.
